# execution order of the following Mysql select query

Tags: mysql

```
create table student
(
ROLL_NO int,
NAME varchar(20),
ADDRESS varchar(20),
PHONE varchar(20),
Age int);

insert into student
values(1,'HARSH','DELHI','9036478414',18),(2,'PRATIK','BIHAR','9945127136',19),
      (3,'RIYANKA','SILIGURI','8618572816',20),(4,'DEEP','RAMNAGAR','8088648668',18),
      (5,'SAPTARHI','KOLKATA','8147513582',19),(6,'DHANRAJ','BARABAJAR','8123186181',20),
      (7,'ROHIT','BALURGHAT','9742111333',18),(8,'NIRAJ','ALIPUR','7851336571',19);

create table studentcourse
(
COURSE_ID int,
ROLL_NO int);

insert into studentcourse
values(1,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,4),(1,5),(4,9),(5,10),(4,11);


select student.name,studentcourse.COURSE_ID
from student right join studentcourse
on studentcourse.ROLL_NO=student.ROLL_NO
union all
select student.NAME,studentcourse.COURSE_ID
from student left join studentcourse
on studentcourse.ROLL_NO=student.ROLL_NO
where student.ROLL_NO is null or studentcourse.COURSE_ID is null;
```

I was trying to get the duplicate null values while doing full join,I thought WHERE Clause gets executed after the FROM and JOIN clauses but union all gets executed before the where clause it seems.so can anyone explain how the above select query gets executed in MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause in the second half of your union query is incorrect because it has this extra term in it:

```sql
student.ROLL_NO
```

Remove it, and use this version:

```
SELECT student.name, studentcourse.COURSE_ID
FROM student
RIGHT JOIN studentcourse
    ON studentcourse.ROLL_NO = student.ROLL_NO
UNION ALL
SELECT student.NAME, studentcourse.COURSE_ID
FROM student
LEFT JOIN studentcourse
    ON studentcourse.ROLL_NO = student.ROLL_NO
WHERE studentcourse.COURSE_ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: anyhow the output will remain the same. my question is how does that whole query get executed? what is the execution order of that query?

Comment: For each half of the union, the joins would happen first, followed by the `WHERE` filter (in the case of the second query).  Then, those two intermediate result sets would be combined via `UNION ALL` to form the final result set.